# Pass text of input to calling function (yes it is possible)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, input

I know this question has been asked -and answered- multiple times. However I found a new solution - but do not fully understand it. The setup is this:

```
<input id="input1" onchange="GetText()"/>
```

All answers i found suggest to use the id to get the value of the input.

```
function GetText(){
  alert($("#input1").val());
}
```

$(this).val() does not work here.

Another way to use the value of the #input1 would be to use this.value in the calling function:

```
<input id="input1" onchange="GetText(this.value)" />
```

This passes the value as a parameter to the function.

However I found a JQuery sample that attaches a function to #input1 and makes $(this).val() work.

```
$("#input1").change(function(e){
alert($(this).val())
});
```

Against all answers here at stackoverflow seeing that it is possible to attach a function to a input field and have access to the value of it - I ask myself how I would have to write this function and not attach it with JQuery. Or can it be only attached with JQuery? Why?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/delcon/64ts5d1s/) is a fidle with this setup to play

Comment: `this` inside a Object method refers to the Object itself.

Comment: No answers suggested to *not* use inline Javascript like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either pass reference to input object as a parameter in inline call to callback like this:

```
<input id="input2" onchange="GetText(this)" />
```

and then in javascript:

```
function GetText(_this){
  alert(_this.value);
}
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/2wncjm0q/)

Or you can attach function directly to input object like so

```
document.getElementById('input2').getText = function() {
    alert(this.value);
};
```

and in html:

```
<input id="input2" onchange="this.getText()" />
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/5su696yo/)

Basically this object in javascript is bound to context, in which the function has been created. When you define function globally, like GetText in your example, this is bound to global object in scope of that function.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input id="input1" onchange="GetText.call(this)"/>
```

or

```
<input id="input1" onchange="GetText.apply(this)"/>
```

Will call the GetText function with the input as the value of this. Then you can use $(this) or this.value within the scope of GetText.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a similar Vanilla JS function that you can put into you're HTML, which I actually don't recommend, because I support JavaScript HTML separation, it would be something like:

```
function getInputVal(context){
  alert(context.value);
}
```

In your HTML:

```
<input id='whoCares' name='whoCares' value='Some Value'  onchange='getInputVal(this)' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Inline JS is not easy to maintain, especially if there's so much of it. It is better to separate your JS and HTML.

```js
//Wait for DOM to load
$(function() {
    //set up change event listener --> anonymous function
    $('#input1').on('change', function() {
        alert( this.value );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input1" />
```

**Or** if you want to use a named function:

```js
//wait for DOM to load
$(function() {
    //Define function
    function GetText(){
      alert( this.value );
    }

    //set up change event listener --> named function
    $('#input1').on('change', GetText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="input1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

> All answers i found suggest to use the id to get the value of the input.

That's actually a pretty bad design; you want to create event handlers that can be unaware of the elements they're attached to.

The example without using jQuery would look like this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input1');
input.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  alert(this.value);
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="input1" />
```

See also: [`addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)